# Needed: MM7 server for .Net

Tags: .net, mm7

I'm looking for MM7 server that can be used within a .Net program, on windows server 2008 environment.

What I found so far:

InetLab [MM7.Net](http://www.inetlab.ru/Products/MM7.aspx) - not very stable on Win2008, but OK,

ActiveXperts [SMS and MMS Toolkit 5.2](http://www.activexperts.com/xmstoolkit/) - only SMS server, no MM7 server.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InetLab released a fixed version of MM7.Net, with a few limitations (currently, the application needs administrator credentials to run properly). So I guess I'll use it on Windows Server 2008.